# Various photos with same focus

Tags: android, camera

I need to take several photos with the same focus distance. I have researched during a while and it seems that is not possible.

The main aim is do a simple autofocus and then use the same distance for all the next photos without calling autofocus anymore.

Android's API have some interesting methods like:

[FOCUS_MODE_FIXED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_FIXED)

But, I can not set the value of the fixed focus. It is set at a hyperfocal distance.

There is also a method:

[getFocusDistances (float[] output).](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusDistances%28float%5B%5D%29)

But there is not a "setter" to set the desired focus distances.

Can I achive my aim or it is not possible?

PD: Some code to explain how I set up the Camera.parameters an how I manage the AF:

```
    AutoFocusCallback aF = new AutoFocusCallback(){

      @Override
      public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
          if(arg0==true){
              Log.d("preview", " Autofocus callback!"); 
              parameters.setFocusMode("fixed");
              updateParameters();
          }

      }};

public static void updateParameters(){
if(camera==null){}
else{
    camera.setParameters(parameters);

}
```

When focusAutoButton is clicked:

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             Preview.parameters.setFocusMode("auto");
             Log.d("focus: ","auto");
             Preview.updateParameters();
             Preview.camera.autoFocus(preview.aF);

        }});
```

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630989&page=1

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using to set up the camera parameters and manage focus?

Answer (score 3):

The details will vary between devices, but you should be able to set the focus mode to `FOCUS_MODE_AUTO` and then call [`Camera.autoFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus%28android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback%29) once to set the focal distance. Unless you explicitly call `autoFocus()` again, the focal distance shouldn't change.

Please note that some devices do not support autofocus, so it's good practice to be defensive when requesting it:

```
try {
     Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
     if (!Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO.equals(params.getFocusMode())) {
        params.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        camera.setParameters(params);
     }
     camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
           // if (success) { ... }
        }
     } );
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
     // Can't use autofocus...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Nevertheless this code does not work on my case. When I call Camera.autofocus() the preview is well focused and I can take a good picture, but when y take the second one (and no autoFocus() is called) the focus seems to move at a hyperfocal distance (like focus_mode_fixed).

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried running your code on a different device? The camera hardware can vary significantly between manufacturers.

Comment: Just rigth now I have tried with another device and has the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Another option might be to call `autoFocus()` and then change the mode to `FOCUS_MODE_FIXED` in the callback if autofocus succeeded.

Comment: That was my fist thought, but FOCUS_MODE_FIXED does not set the focus where it is, it only puts the focal distance to infinity  regardless of the previous focal distance.

Comment: Its a pitty that I am using API 10, because the solution would be described in the same API: 

Since API level 14, applications can call autoFocus(AutoFocusCallback) in this mode (CONTINIUOUS_VIDEO). The focus callback will immediately return with a boolean that indicates whether the focus is sharp or not. The focus position is locked. after autoFocus call

Comment: Have you tried using that method despite the older API version? I assumed that you would be using `CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`, but I've used `CONTINUOUS_VIDEO` together with `autoFocus()` on some 2.3.3 devices (API 10) without any problem. The focus remains locked. Be sure to watch for `RuntimeException`s, though. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using CONTINIUOUS_VIDEO because my devide does not support CONTINIUOUS_PICTURE. I tryied to use it doing:

1-Setting camera.paramenters.setFocusMode to "continiuous-video"
when the user clicks a button on my User Interface.

2-Creating AutoFocusCallback on my Preview class.

The API says: Stopping preview with stopPreview(), or triggering still image capture with takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback), will not change the the focus position. Applications must call cancelAutoFocus to reset the focus. But thats seems to not work.